# bluetooth dongle not paring

Tags: usb, bluetooth, dongle

My audio speaker is detected by the bluetooth dongle (brand integral) but it fail to pair.
Note, it's OK with another usb dongle brand.

The dongle is delivered with windows drivers CD, can i install it on Ubuntu ?

Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You cannot install a windows driver on Ubuntu, but there is a high likelihood that there is a driver for Ubuntu. What is the model of your dongle?

Comment: Integral USB mini 2.0

Comment: Please [edit] your question with details of your BT chip (see output of `hciconfig -a` but remove private data before posting).

Comment: Which private data's must I remove ? My Name ?

Answer (score 0):

To use Windows network device drivers in Ubuntu, you might try [ndiswrapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NDISwrapper). This answer might help: [How do I get drivers (especially WLAN/bluetooth) working on HP Envy dv6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251859/how-do-i-get-drivers-especially-wlan-bluetooth-working-on-hp-envy-dv6)

Comment: Thanks, but I expected something easier !